# How do I properly write a module to be compatible with Bluebird's `PromisifyAll`

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Let's say in a node.js module, `moduleA.js`, I have the following object with a bunch of node-style async functions:

```
// moduleA.js

var init = function (data, callback) {
    return callback(null, data.params );
};

var delay = function(data, callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(null, data);
    }, 1000*3);
}


var reverse = function(data, callback) {
    var j,
        d = {};

    for(j in data) {
        d[ data[j] ] = j;
    }

    callback(null, d);

}

module.exports = {
    init: init,
    delay: delay,
    reverse: reverse
};
```

I consume `moduleA.js` in `main.js` and can successfully `promisify` each method individually, like:

```
// main.js
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    modA = require('./moduleA') );

var data = {
    "a": "one",
    "b": "two",
    "c": "three",
    "d": "four"
};


Promise.promisify(modA.init)(data)

    .then( Promise.promisify(modA.delay) )

    .then( Promise.promisify(modA.reverse) )

    .then(function(data){

        res.send(data);

    }).catch(function(e){
        next(e);
    });
```

The above code works just fine, but is more verbose than desired.

My question is, how would I modify my module to allow `Promise.promisifyAll` to work properly on the entire exported object? I want to avoid `promisification` inside the module and allow others to optionally `promisify` it upon consumption.

I've unsuccessfully tried many variations of the following:

```
// main.js
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    modA = require('./moduleA') ),
    modAPromised = Promise.promisifyAll(modA);

var data = {
    "a": "one",
    "b": "two",
    "c": "three",
    "d": "four"
};

modAPromised.initAsync(data)

    .then(modAPromised.delayAsync)

    .then(modAPromised.reverseAsync)

    .then(function(data){

        res.send(data);

    }).catch(function(e){
        next(e);
    });
```

When I do this, I get and error which says `Cannot call method 'delay' of undefined`. `Promise.promisifyAll` is adding all the `Async` functions as expected:

```
// console.log(modAPromised);

{
    init: [Function],
    delay: [Function],
    reverse: [Function],
    initAsync: {
        [Function] __isPromisified__: true
    },
    delayAsync: {
        [Function] __isPromisified__: true
    },
    reverseAsync: {
        [Function] __isPromisified__: true
    }
}
```

but I think something is screwy with the context. It appears that internally `delayAsync` tries to invoke `this.delay` but `this` is undefined.

So, how would I modify my module to allow `Promise.promisifyAll` to work properly on the entire exported object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just make a dual API with `.nodeify`? That would be even easier for the consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`promisifyAll` creates methods that are dependent on `this` because `this` is not known when you pass a class prototype to it from which multiple objects will be created.

For example:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("redis"));

// In another file
var redis = require("redis");
var client1 = redis.createClient(...);
var client2 = redis.createClient(...);

client1.putAsync(...);
client2.putAsync(...);
```

There was nothing to bind to when `"redis"` was promisified, and those methods are dependent on the specific `client` instances. `.putAsync` cannot just call `put` - it needs to call `put` both in the context of `client1` and `client2` depending how `putAsync` was called.

A solution was suggested to someone having the same problem but he never responded: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/470.

---

Your module could be implemented  as dual API utilizing nodeify, that way consumers don't even need the promisification:

```
var init = function (data, callback) {
    return Promise.resolve(data.params).nodeify(callback);
};

var delay = function(data, callback) {
    return Promise.delay(data, 1000 * 3).nodeify(callback);
}

var reverse = function(data, callback) {
    var j,
        d = {};

    for(j in data) {
        d[ data[j] ] = j;
    }

    return Promise.resolve(d).nodeify(callback);
}
```

Comment: Hm, but for those properties that are statically known you could directly refer to the method by closure? Using `put = redis.prototype.put;` and `put.call(this)` instead of `this.put()`

Comment: @Bergi yes but reflective calls are much slower (at least they were when this was implemented) but that could have changed by now. I will need to benchmark it - in that case we can avoid adding yet another option so thanks for the idea.

Comment: Oh I forgot how much you care about performance :-) You might also screen the method on whether it uses `this` at all (don't you do decompilation anyway?) and if not even omit the `.call(this, `.

Comment: @Bergi I don't do decompilation just compilation .. but that's a neat trick too.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is less with `moduleA.js` and more with your usage in `main.js`.

If you explicitly call your promisified functions within your `.then()` statements, your module will work correctly:

```
// main.js
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    modA = require('./moduleA'),
    modAPromised = Promise.promisifyAll(modA);

var data = {
    "a": "one",
    "b": "two",
    "c": "three",
    "d": "four"
};

modAPromised.initAsync(data)

    .then(function(data) {
        return modAPromised.delayAsync(data);
    })

    .then(function(data) {
        return modAPromised.reverseAsync(data);
    })

    .then(function(data){

        res.send(data);

    }).catch(function(e){
        next(e);
    });
```

As for **why** this is, I'm honestly not sure. I have a strong suspicion that `promisifyAll` does some context binding that `promise` does not do. That would explain why wrapping your methods in a clean function would fix the issue.

I'm sure the Bluebird maintainers would know more, if you want to get specifics on the implementation.